# How to change active culture on Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, globalization

[Update] I see I need the full example to explain.

In my Windows Phone 7 App, I got a page containing a TextBox bound to a Decimal "Amount":

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Amount,Mode=TwoWay}" InputScope="CurrencyAmount"/>
```

The phone settings are set to German. In german localization, a value like 1234.56m would be formatted 1.234,56 (unlike the US, where it should be 1,234.56).

Problem is, when I enter a value like 1.234,56 in the textbox, the content will be interpreted for US, resulting in 1.23456m, when it should have been 1234.56m.

So, how do I get the binding on the WP7 to use the current phone culture instead of a generic US one? In Germany people expect to enter a colon for decimals instead of a dot.

Comment: that's definately strange.  i'd think the app would just **be** the right culture...are you using german resources,etc, so the app knows it supports the german culture?

Comment: Actually, the funny thing is: for ToString() the correct german locale is being used. Just the binding is off.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the Settings app's region & language section?

The silverlight related localization stuff is all [here at msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838238%28VS.95%29.aspx).

There's another windows phone 7 specific localization [blog post](http://programmeramera.se/post/Localize-you-Windows-Phone-7-Applications.aspx) too.

Comment: Seems my question was confusing: I added the problem source to my question.